# Why does \leq show up as \le?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, sharelatex

My only two packages are `amsmath` and `amsfonts`. When I type `\leq`, it shows up as if I had typed `\le`. How do I do the actual less-than-equals (`>=`) sign?

Edit: I typed `\leq` and the output symbol was `>`, but I want `>=`. I am also using the site sharelatex.com as my editor.

I think something was wrong with sharelatex, as when I closed my project and reopened, everything was fine.

Comment: `\le` and  `\leq` produce the same output.

Comment: If you want two symbols, a `>` and a `=`, type the two characters separately.

Comment: Are you maybe thinking of `leqslant`, in which the equality-side bar is also slanted?

Comment: Please show a complete (preferably minimal) document that reproduces the issue.

Comment: No I'm thinking of one symbol, >=, but I don't have this symbol on my keyboard. It is not slanted.

Comment: Nobody writes `>=` except when nothing else is available, in pure ASCII context such as newsgroups or similar situations.   If you can type `>` and `=`, then `$a>=b$` will do what you want; but it's wrong and ugly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as your comment to the accepted answer indicates that your problem is not related to LaTeX.

Comment: @user49915 In a programming language, `>=` could be a keyword by itself, so it's a different case. As are decorations.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`\le` and `\leq` are synonyms, as are `\ge` and `\geq`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\[ a\leq b \le c \]
\[ a\geq b \ge c \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

These symbols are defined in `fontmath.ltx`, part of the LaTeX kernel:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leq}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"14}
   \let\le=\leq
\DeclareMathSymbol{\geq}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"15}
   \let\ge=\geq
```

Comment: @Sigur I closed and reopened sharelatex and the problem didn't happen anymore. I thought it must have been a sharelatex problem.
This answer was very comprehensive and did help me realize it wasn't something about LaTeX I didn't understand (as I'm new with this).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps another symbol is meant, with a `=` symbol, stacked under `<`, which can be obtained with `\leqq` from `MnSymbol` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}

\[ \le \] is another symbol than \[ \leqq \]

but means the same mathematical relation. 


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`amssymb` provides `\leqq` and `\geqq` if you badly need it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
  \[ a\leqq b \]
  \[ a\geqq b \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amssymb also provides those commands if you don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you can use a virtual keyboard on your computer to type `>=`.

Second, using `MnSymbol` to type the characters in math mode. This is the sample code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}
    \[
        \equal
    \]
    \[
        \gtr
    \]
    \[
        \less
    \]
    \[
        \gtr\equal
    \]
    \[
        \less\equal
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]