# \ge and \geq vs \geqslant (and similarly with \le, \leq, and \leqslant)?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, amssymb

I have read that `\ge` and `\geq` are the same, but I have also seen `\geqslant` in various contexts before. What is the preference between `\ge` (AKA `\geq`) and `\geqslant`? Similarly, what is the preference between `\le` (AKA `\leq`) and `\leqslant`?

**EDIT**: I am aware that `\le` and `\leq` are the same, and similarly with `\ge` and `\geq`. My question is about the preference between using those and `\leqslant` & `\geqslant`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does \leq show up as \le?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182620/why-does-leq-show-up-as-le) (partial duplicate)

Comment: it's just the difference between ≤ and  ⩽

Comment: asking for preference is like asking for a preference between red and blue, there is no general answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The general mathematical community, as I understand it, still usually preferences one over the other for these sorts of related commands, at least for certain contexts. Some clarification on why both exist, for example, might be helpful.

Comment: @Mel as a side note, you can write code by using only one single ` at each side of the code instead of three of them ;).

Comment: @manooooh thanks for the info. In the documentation for writing the posts, it always says ``` `code` ```, and so I assumed you needed three.

Comment: As far as I know, the slanted version is mainly used in France.

Comment: I don't think so. I see both used interchangeably. I prefer the slanted one myself, but the default tex version (without ams fonts) is the non slant one with an end result that you see a compete mixture of both.

Comment: the three back ticks are for code blocks singe backticks are for inline code

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that clarifies the difference between the two ways to use backticks well. Thanks!

Comment: You can use the variant you prefer, so long as you always use the same across the whole document. You may even say in the document preamble `\renewcommand{\ge}{\geqslant}\renewcommand{\geq}{\geqslant}`, so you can use `\ge` or `\geq` and be sure you'll always come up with the same symbol. And this allows you to change your mind: commenting out those instructions, the symbols will change their shape at the next LaTeX run.

Comment: @egreg would that be a good idea for general-purpose writing in LaTeX or might it be confusing to people trying to check my code?

Comment: @Mel To the contrary: if somebody checks your code, they’ll see `\leq`, say, and understand what you *mean*, independently of the typographic realization.

Comment: @egreg That helps a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The symbols `\leq` (`\le`) and `\leqslant` have exactly the same meaning; similarly for `\geq` (`\ge`) and `\geqslant`.  The preference for one or the other is basically subjective, but this is also affected by the house styles of major publishers of mathematics, which presumably traces back to the founding editors of journals handled by those publishers.

The four commands representing forms with horizontal equal member are all defined in `plain.tex`, and brought from there into LaTeX.  This was a Knuth decision; the reason isn't known, but may be a desire to minimize typing.  The slant forms were added in `amsfonts` by "popular demand", i.e., author pressure.

All four shapes have unique Unicode ids.  The slanted forms were added as part of the STIX effort, as requested by publishers.

Answer (score 5):

Taken from the answer to [Why does \leq show up as \le?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182620):

> These symbols are defined in `fontmath.ltx`, part of the LaTeX kernel:
>
> ```
> \DeclareMathSymbol{\leq}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"14}
>    \let\le=\leq
> \DeclareMathSymbol{\geq}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"15}
>    \let\ge=\geq
> ```

Meaning that `\le` is identical to `\leq` (a synonym). Same is true for `\ge` and `\geq`.

---

Taken from the answer to [Slanted greater than and equal to, less than and equal to](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167786):

> You need the `amssymb` package in order to use the `\leqslant` and
>   `\geqslant` symbols.

---

My "answer" was before the edit to the question was made:

> **EDIT**: I am aware that `\le` and `\leq` are the same, and similarly with `ge` and `\geq`. My question is about the
>   preference between using those and `\leqslant` & `\geqslant`.

Comment: This clarification is helpful as to how exactly these commands work, even if it did not answer my question completely. Thanks!